# Easy way to output a file and change the implicit newlines ($) in the file into literal (\n)

Tags: linux, bash, sed, vim, printf

I have a file with a number of invisible Newlines. In Vim it's shown as `$` (can be seen with `:set list`). I had a hard time to convert them to an output which is represented as a one line string with the literal `\n` string instead of the invincible `$`.

Example:

```
# cat file.txt 
test
file
with
newlines
```

To see the newlines in vim enter :set list.

With this command, I could format the output as wanted:

```
# awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}' file.txt 
test\nfile\nwith\nnewlines\n
```

however, I think there should be an easier way with `sed`, `echo` or `printf`

Comment: They're not invincible, or even invisible. They're `LF` characters. Look using `od -bc file.txt`

Answer (score 3):

**Answer using `sed` of GNU version:**

```
sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g' file.txt
```

Use the `z` option of `sed` to avoid splitting the file's contents by newlines.

**Answer using `echo`:**

```
xargs -I {} echo -n '{}\n' < file.txt
```

By `xargs`, `echo` outputs adding `\n` for each file line.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
awk -v ORS='\\n' 1 infile
```

or a bit more compact:

```
awk 1 ORS='\\n' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Using standard `sed`:

```
H
1h
$ {
    g
    s/\n/\\n/g
    s/$/\\n/
}
$! d
```

That is, append the current line to the *hold space* (overwrite the hold space if it's the first line).  If we're at the last line, get the hold space with `g`, then replace each literal newline character with `\n` and insert `\n` at the very end too, then implicitly print the buffer by getting to the end of the script.  If we're not at the last line, then skip to the next cycle without implicitly printing the current buffer.

On the command line:

```bsh
sed -e H -e 1h -e '${ g; s/\n/\\n/g; s/$/\\n/; }' -e '$!d' file
```

This output all the lines of the input concatenated together with the two characters `\n` as the delimiter.  There will be a newline character at the end of the output.

Answer (score 0):

`perl` :

```
perl -00pe 's/\n/\\n/g' file
```

if you like to visually see the `LF` character at the end.

---

Otherwise if you would like to cut off it without seeing the output (The `\n` character) on the console use a simple `transliteration` :

```
cat file | tr '\n' '\\'
```